Can I make a \fullcite in biblatex without the author's name?
How can I define a command \fullcite* such that it's equal to \fullcite but not including the authors's names? (More or less in the same way as \cite* works with respect to \cite.)

Try this cite command:
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\fullcite}
    {\renewbibmacro*{author}{}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}%
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
    \usebibmacro{multicitedelim}}%
    {}%

Cite with the \fullcite*{〈entrykey〉}.
